# React Hook "useCategory" cannot be called inside a callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here is my code

```
import React, { FC, useState,useMemo } from "react";

const FormSearch: FC<{ params: string }> = ({
   params 
}) => {
  const [category, useCategory] = useState<string>("All");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>("");
  useMemo(() => {             
     const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
    if (!!searchParams.get("Categories")&&!!searchParams.get("Search")) {
          useCategory(`${searchParams.get("Categories")}`); 
          setSearch(`${searchParams.get("Search")}`);   
    } else {
      setSearch("");
      useCategory("All")
    }
  }, [params]);

  return (
    <div>1000</div>
  );
};
```

I get these errors

Line 16:  React Hook "useCategory" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 20:   React Hook "useCategory" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: React hooks must only be called from a React function, either React function component or custom hook.

Comment: @ Ulug Toprak I am breaking the rules "Do not call hooks within loops, conditions, or nested functions." ??

Comment: @Ulug Toprak  I just wrote it wrong useCategory it was necessary setCategory

Answer (score 27):

You should not use the useCategory to set your `category` state, it will detected by react as its hooks. Rename it to `setCategory` will solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

The problem relies on that you are putting your hook inside a condition.

According to the documentation, you should do something like this:

```
  useEffect(function persistForm() {
    //  We're not breaking the first rule anymore
    if (name !== '') {
      localStorage.setItem('formData', name);
    }
  });
```

Where as you are creating an effect that has the condition inside of it. Remember that Hooks must be called on the top level of the components.

You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)